# Какой принцип ООП реализуют замыкания?

Tags: javascript

Или с помощью замыканий ......

Comment: никакой *(3 символа нужно...)*

Comment: Использовать замыкания для наследования и для полиморфизма - это какой-то поликостылизм :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замыкания сами по себе не реализуют никакой принцип. Это просто один из механизмов языка.

Но если вопрос на самом деле звучал как "Какой принцип ООП обычно реализуется с помощью замыканий" - то ответ: инкапсуляция.

Дело в том, что в JS нет модификаторов доступа  - аналогов `private` / `public` / `protected` из C++/C#/Java.

На Java/C#  модификаторы доступа позволяют скрыть то, как именно класс хранит данные - например, скрыть факт, что возраст пользователя хранится в поле `_age` - достаточно просто поставить на поле private, и добавить методы `getAge` / `setAge`, через которые можно контролировать процесс установки возраста.

На JavaScript нельзя скрыть детали реализации - т.е. в ваше поле `_age` снаружи может влезть любой желающий, в обход  `getAge` / `setAge`.

Стаднартное решение - вместо поля использовать локальную переменную, и использовать замыкание на нее в методах `getAge` / `setAge`. Эта переменная не будет видна снаружи (т.к. это локальная переменная в методе, не поле объекта).

```
function User (name, age) {
    this.name = name; // видна снаружи
    var _age = age;   // не видна снаружи
    this.getAge = function() {
        return _age;
    }
    this.setAge = function(age) {
        if(typeof age === "number" && age >0 && age<110){
            _age = age;
        } else {
            console.log("Недопустимое значение");
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Код взят с metanit, https://metanit.com/web/javascript/4.7.php</sub>